# How do I list wp posts with releated images?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like to list posts in Wordpress and related images. How do I write the mysql_query($ask) in mysql?

I can join two tables but not sure how to do it as I need to use wp_posts two times via wp_postmeta, as I understand it.

Comment: What would you consider as "related"?

Comment: Doesn't wp_posts store information about images in wp_postmeta which in turn relate back to the image in wp_posts?

Comment: Btw, strange question. Do you know php, mysql, WP?

Comment: I'm generally familiar with the software -- I just wanted to make sure you weren't expecting _semantically_ related images.

Comment: @PalBergstrom, A word of warning: you almost _never_ need to write sql queries in WordPress. There's a built in function for nearly everything you need, and if you start writing sql to get stuff, you may regret it later.

Comment: If you can explain in more detail what you mean by "related" images, I can maybe steer you to some functions to look at.

Comment: I see. Not sure what you mean but I'm talking about pure mysql, JOIN, LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN, and such.

Comment: Thanks for answers but I should probably not have added the tag "wordpress". If you don't know php and mysql then the question isn't for you.

Comment: So you want to get a certain of posts with the featured image with a single query?

Comment: @justkidding96 Yes!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a custom handmade query to perform this. You only need to run the Wordpress loop and get the releated images for each post. Try this simple code :)

```
<?php if ( have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```